# Is add_imports_to_deepest_scope setting in .editorconfig the same as AddImportsToDeepestScope setting in .DotSettings?

Tags: c#, resharper

When I set add_imports_to_deepest_scope=true:error in my .editorconfig file, it has no effect (Resharper still puts using directives outside of a namespace). I made sure that Resharper is aware of my .editorconfig and also that .editorconfig overrides Resharper's settings.

When I set AddImportsToDeepestScope to true in Resharper settings, however, it starts to do what I want.

The add_imports_to_deepest_scope setting is listed on the Resharper website, so I assume it should work the same. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The setting in question is a ReSharper setting, and ReSharper settings currently do not allow mixing inspection severities (like error or warning) with setting values. Besides, there are currently no inspections in ReSharper that check the placement of using directives. So please simply write "true" instead of "true:error".